# React component from node package not rendering

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've a React Component which is part of a node package which I am using in my code. The component doesn't render and I don't see anything pertaining to it on the console or within the React tab on the console. Is there a way to debug and know what's going on inside what is seeming like a blackhole?

I tried to pull it in locally but I don't know how to do an `import` on a local package. `import Component from 'package'` doesn't seem to work. I tried using the relative path, it seems to work in terminal upon cd'ing but when I do `npm run start` I get Module not found, Error can't resolve path. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Which package are you struggling with? It should has a repository, some docs, issues...

Comment: It's an internal package. I should probably reach out to the owners but was wondering if I could do something at my end.